# Retrieve Azure VM FQDN

Tags: azure, powershell

I am looking for a way to check if we have Azure Virtual machines that are not domain joined. I am looking for a PS command or script to query the entire Azure VM estate and return a list with all VMs ideally in csv format. Those VMs that are not domain joined will be a subject to another task, of course - join to the domain.

The command which works fine to retrieve the FQDN is

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2 -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select Name, Domain
```

However, this works only for individual machine. I was told to use foreach loop to query all VMs but I don't know how.

Psremoting is enabled and tested OK, same for WSMAN.

Comment: Please be sure to only include properly-formatted text, not images of text. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) to learn why this is important.

Answer (score 0):

*Here is the foreach command to find the list of VM's and domain names.*

```
connect-azaccount
$vmlist=get-azvm | select -Property Name
foreach( $item in $vmlist){
Get-WmiObject  -Namespace root\cimv2 -ComputerName $item  -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select Name, Domain
}
```

[image]

*If you want to use `get-wmiobject` cmdlet you need to enable `wsman` Here is the document for using enabling [wsman](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.wsman.management/connect-wsman?view=powershell-7.2).*

*Instead of `wsman` you can even run `get-computerinfo` if you run this command, you will get a property called `csdomain` which is the information of domain name.*

[image]

Comment: Thank you! However, I can't make it work for some reason. I enabled wsman, I gave it a try with get-computerobject too but I am in some kind of a loop. It only returns the subscription and do not proceed further to query the VM domain names Screenshot above

Comment: have you enabled remote PowerShell on those VMS if not try using invoke script to do so.

Comment: @Boboswae - please edit your question with such details (especially command-line content that needs to be formatted) - very hard to read as a comment, and really needs to be part of your question.

Comment: @SaiSakethGuduru-MT - as I mentioned already under the question, content really needs to be formatted text, not images of text (see [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)). You can still remove sensitive content with text, by editing the text vs blurring an image.

Comment: Edited. Sorry. I am new here.